# Why trinidad TreeTable emptyText doesnot print the text message?

Tags: jsp

[image]i am doing fixing an bug in an already developed application, and i am new to jsp.
So i am not aware about this issue.

this is the code in .jsp file

```
<tr:panelGroupLayout  partialTriggers="deleteFeaturePointId updateFP  OnsearchFeatures onClearFields">

<tr:panelBox contentStyle="overflow:auto;width:950px;height:200px;color:#FFFFFF;" >
<tr:treeTable emptyText="No Record Found"  value="#{featurePointBean.model}" 
styleClass="grid_hdg_txt" var="foo" 
inlineStyle="text-align:left;" expandAllEnabled="false" 
initiallyExpanded="true"  binding="#{featurePointBean.featurePointTableId}" 
rowBandingInterval="1"  width="100%" rootNodeRendered="false" 
verticalGridVisible="false"
partialTriggers="updateFP OnsearchFeatures onClearFields" 
autoSubmit="true" immediate="true" >
```

But the problem is that when the the table component in null, it should diplay "No records found " message. but its not displaying anything such and giving a empty table.? So what would be the issue i am not able to understand. 
Any suggestions what could be done?

the Output is like below screen

Comment: Does it throw any exception?

Comment: No It doesn't throw any exception, it simply gives a empty table. @RomanC

Comment: I have uploaded an screen that shows the output with empty table area, where i need to display some message like "No record found"  when the table is empty. @RomanC

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here was that, the table was not empty in the backend because In its respective bean class an empty  DTO was being added to the treetable.
It simply need a null check to avoid this empty DTO getting added to the tree table.
this is how i changed the code and that worked fine.

```
            imageGroupNameDropList = featurePointDAO.getAvailableImageGroups(installId);
                        if(imageGroupNameDropList.size()!=0)
                        {   
                        availableFeaturePoints = featurePointDAO.searchFeaturePoints("",
                                "", getUserId(), getInstallId());
                        TreeNodeBean imageGroups = _createNode("Image Group Names");
                        root.add(0, imageGroups);
                        ArrayList<TreeNodeBean> featurePointNodes = new ArrayList<TreeNodeBean>();
                        ArrayList<TreeNodeBean> imageGroupNodes = new ArrayList<TreeNodeBean>()...
        >
        >
        >...
    for (FeaturePointDTO featurePointDTO : entry.getValue()) {
                        TreeNodeBean featurePoints = _createNode(
                                featurePointDTO.getImageGroupName(),
                                featurePointDTO);
                        featurePointNodes.add(featurePoints);
                    }
                    imageGroupName.setChildren(featurePointNodes);
}
```

Comment: So this worked fine. Learnt a lesson today that Small Things troubles a lot.